# how to insert 3 rows as per my conditions with pl/sql code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have to insert 3 rows in a table as per my conditions. 
let's assume 3 insert statement are insert A, insert B, insert C.

if INSERT A success then automatically INSERT C also should be executed and as well as INSERT C success then automatically insert A should be executed.

if both A & C  failed then only insert B should be executed.

Comment: Conditions you wrote are wrong. You never insert B, but A >> C >> A. Where's B? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: sorry.. i have corrected the conditions now. littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant (while discussing it with @XING); don't mind WHEN OTHERS, it just shows that *something* will need to be handled.

```
  begin
    insert into A values (1);        --> if this succeeds, 
    insert into B values (1);        --> insert into B will automatically follow
  exception
    when others then                 --> if anything goes wrong above
      insert into C values (1);      --> insert into C will be done.
  end;                               --> But, what if it fails? Could that happen?
                                     --> If so, it'll have to be handled as well.
```

Comment: where is this part 'if INSERT A success then automatically INSERT C also should be executed '?

Comment: @brenners, as I've said (in a comment below the question), conditions are wrongly stated so I have no idea what should follow what, really. This piece of code is here to show the principle (at least,  the way I understood it).